# heroku rails "load error expected app/app/model" instead just "app/model"

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Rails 2 application running well on my local machine at the moment. But fails on Heroku, here's the log: http://pastie.org/1957572

I can't figure out why the path is "app/app/model/.." instead of just "app/model...", is there anything I need to config my Rails app for Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured this out, but it's because /app is the root folder for apps on Heroku

It's like if you had it on your own VPS and it was in /var/www, then the error would read like "/var/www/app..."